# SQL multi value id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have .csv excel file (comma delimited) - table bellow, which I would like to import into database. After I import the csv, it only saves first record from tech_id (so 64 and 101). How do I make it import more values, which are separated by ;.

```
+--------+------------+-------------+---+-------------+
|   id   |   start    |     end     |...|   tech_id   |
+--------+------------+-------------+---+-------------+
| 10883  | 27/3/2016  | 28/3/2016   |...|  64;15;259  |
| 10884  | 27/3/2016  | 4/4/2016    |...|     17      |
| 10885  | 28/3/2016  | 1/4/2016    |...|   101;29    |
+--------+------------+-------------+---+-------------+
```

Comment: maybe show the DB records you achieved and the mechanism you used to import. Is that from a DB tool of some kind?

Comment: Use this as a beachhead to *not* save data like this in the future. Unless you don't like indexes.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items, (or semi-colon separated.) It will only cause you lots of trouble!

Comment: Obviously you are already trying to parse tech_id (**but you are not telling us how** - [edit] your question) and this does not work. Do this in two steps. First import the table as it is now, with tech_id in a string field. You question then becomes how to 'multiply' the record with `101;29` into two with `101` and `29` respectively. You are also not telling us whether you have to do this one time, or it has to be done repeatedly, which makes a whole lot of difference for the possible answers.

Comment: I would like to save it in another format , but SAP is not having any other option :( And of course I would like to import it automatically. CRON script is fetching this .csv which is later imported into another database. And this import didn' save other values in tech_id. Is there any other option, which will make it easier (without any other parsing, or running through some other script)?